# How to select all clusters, in a dendrogram, below a certain cutoff, in r

Tags: r, cut, dendrogram

I have a distance matrix, 227 columns by 227 rows called

```
"X9_resid_matrix"
```

This matrix represents 227 proteins and tells me how different each one is from each other. Therefore at the top right corner there is a zero because 1,1 represents the same protein therefore they are identical or zero different. The numbers range from 0 - 9.

Then I used the following command to make a dendrogram:

```
"plot(hclust(as.dist(X9_resid_matrix)))"
```

The y axis goes ranges from zero to nine.

I would like the computer to tell me only the clusters that are below a certain cutoff.

Meaning if there are only 31 clusters that are zero distance, I would like a code that the computer will use to tell me what are those 31 clusters that are zero distance.

The command:

```
cutree(hc, h=0)
```

does not seem to do that when I run it.

For example:
I have the following dendrogram:
[Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3hjX.jpg)

I would like a command that cuts the dendrogram at a height of 1, and only displays 1 and 2.

Comment: What do you get when you run `cutree(hc, h = 0)` ? Is the output just an integer sequence from 1 to 227? If so you might try increasing `h` by a marginal amount to say `1e-07`

Comment: When I run the cutree command it tells me which cluster each of the 227 numbers fit into. I want only the ones below the cutoff, not above.

Comment: I'm not clear on the output you are looking for. Are you able to edit your question to include a small example and show the result you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is `cut`, which takes a dendrogram object `x` and slices it at height `h` to produce a two-element list. The first element, "upper" is the original tree after pruning, and the second element, "lower" is a list containing the trimmed branches (see `?dendrogram` for more details).

Each of the branches in the "lower" element are dendrograms in their own right, and can be plotted and manipulated as usual. Here's a small example:

```
newick <- "((Human:0.01,Chimp:0.03):0.02,(((Whale:0.04,Cow:0.01):0.01,Pig:0.01):0.01,(Dog:0.01,Cat:0.01):0.01):0.04);"
install.packages("phylogram")
dendro <- phylogram::read.dendrogram(text = newick)
plot(dendro)
```

[image: tree plot]

The dendrogram object can then be cross-sectioned with the `cut` command:

```
obj <- cut(dendro, h = 0.09)
obj
```

This outputs a list that looks like this:

```
$upper
'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 2 members total, at height 0.1 

$lower
$lower[[1]]
'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 2 members total, at height 0.08 

$lower[[2]]
'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 5 members total, at height 0.06
```

Notice that the second element `obj$lower` contains two subtrees that resulted from cutting the original tree at height 0.09. To extract and plot say the second of these subtrees just use standard list subsetting syntax:

```
subtree <- obj$lower[[2]]
plot(subtree)
```

[image: subtree plot]

To convert your hc object into a dendrogram you can use the `as.dendrogram` function.

Comment: The cut function does not work for my dendrogram. I get the error: "Error in cut.default(hc, h = 1) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: My dendrogram is from a distance matrix created on excel, X9_resid_matrix. Then: hc <- hclust(as.dist(X9_resid_matrix). Then plot(hc).

Comment: The `cut` function will only work on "dendrogram" objects, not "hclust" ones. You need to convert first, eg `dnd <- as.dendrogram(hc)`. Then You can use the `cut` function eg `cut(dnd, h = 1)`.